# How connect to MS SQL Server from local to VPS using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, vps

I had already success to connect my CI with MS SQL in local.

Now I want to place my web source in VPS A and MS SQL Server in VPS B.
And open port 1433 in VPS B.

But now I can't connect from Source in VPS A to MS SQL in VPS B.

In MS SQL Server Management I can connect from local to Database VPS B .

This is my config in CI:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'port' => '1433',
    'hostname' => 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx',
    'username' => 'test',
    'password' => '123456',
    'database' => 'databasename',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => TRUE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: what are the error messages ?

Comment: Is allowed inbound connection to 1433 on VPS B?